# Change the font type and the background color of navbar menu

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have a shiny app and I  would like to change the font typeand the background color of the navbar menu.
[image]

I have used 'Inspect' on this after running the app and I found that this element is:

```
a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-value="More">
                  More
                  <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
```

but im not familiar with css.

```
ui <- function(){

bootstrapPage('',

            navbarPage(title = 'Hello colour changed',
                       navbarMenu("More",
                                  tabPanel("Table"

                                  ),
                                  tabPanel("About"

                                  )
                       )),

            tags$style(type = 'text/css', '.navbar { background-color: #252525;
                       font-family: Arial;
                       font-size: 13px;
                       color: #FF0000; }',

                       '.navbar-dropdown { background-color: #252525;
                       font-family: Arial;
                       font-size: 13px;
                       color: #FF0000; }',

                       '.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
                       color: #cc3f3e;
            }'

            ))

            }

            server <- function(input, output, session){
            }


            shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below will change the background colour, text colour of the nav-bar, and you can also set the `font-family` to change font type.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- function(){
  navbarPage(title = 'Hello colour change',
             tabPanel("title2"),
             tabPanel("title3"),

             tags$style(type = 'text/css', 
                        '.navbar { background-color: red;}',
                        '.navbar-default .navbar-brand{color: white;}',
                        '.tab-panel{ background-color: red; color: white}'

             ))
  }

server <- function(input, output, session){
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I have edited based on your answer to show that the navbar menu remains the same

Comment: Just try the above I have edited, I guess there was some problem in my css code.